# Expand Text of Compact Data

Tags: data-manipulation, transpose

I am stuck with some data manipulation.
This is a small portion of the input data (df):

```
site=c("C000-C002","C420-C421,C424")
histology=c("9835-9836","9811-9812,9837")
category=c("Leukemia","Leukemia")
df=data.frame(site,histology,category)
```

And this is what I want the processed data to look like:
[image: output format]

You may assume Site and Histology are both 4-digit after text splitting.
In case anyone is interested, the full data table is [here](https://seer.cancer.gov/iccc/iccc-who2008.html)

Please help with the text processing, or if anyone knows an existing processed package or database in a similar format as the image, that would be great too.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R language. So I tried with Javascript as following.

```js
function mapStartEnd(start, end) {
  let list = [];
  let info = {};

  const siteStart = start.match(/([A-Z])(\d{3})/);
  if (siteStart) {
    const siteEnd = end.match(/([A-Z])(\d{3})/);
    info = {
      type: "site",
      prefix: siteStart[1],
      numLength: 3,
      from: parseInt(siteStart[2], 10),
      to: parseInt(siteEnd[2], 10),
    };
  }

  const histologyStart = start.match(/\d{4}/);
  if (histologyStart) {
    const histologyEnd = end.match(/\d{4}/);
    info = {
      type: "histology",
      prefix: "",
      numLength: 4,
      from: parseInt(histologyStart[0], 10),
      to: parseInt(histologyEnd[0], 10),
    };
  }

  const categoryStart = start.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/);
  if (categoryStart) {
    const categoryEnd = end.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/);
    info = {
      type: "category",
      prefix: "",
      numLength: 0,
      from: categoryStart[0],
      to: categoryEnd[0],
    };
  }

  if (!info.numLength) {
    list = [info.from, info.to];
  } else {
    for (let i = info.from; i <= info.to; i++) {
      list.push(info.prefix + i.toString().padStart(info.numLength, "0"));
    }
  }

  return list;
}

function c(list) {
  return list.map((list2) => {
    return list2.split(",").reduce((prev, cur) => {
      const [start, end] = cur.split("-");
      if (!end) prev.push(start);
      else prev = [...prev, ...mapStartEnd(start, end)];
      return prev;
    }, []);
  });
}

function map3(sites, histologys, categorys) {
  let list = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    const site = sites[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < histologys.length; j++) {
      const histology = histologys[j];
      for (let k = 0; k < categorys.length; k++) {
        const category = categorys[k];
        // JSON format
        // list.push({ site, histology, category });

        // CSV format
        list.push(`${site},${histology},${category}`);
      }
    }
  }

  return list;
}
function frame(sites, histologys, categorys) {
  let list = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    const site = sites[i];
    const histology = histologys[i];
    const category = categorys[i];
    list = [...list, ...map3(site, histology, category)];
  }

  return list;
}

const site = c(["C000-C002", "C420-C421,C424"]);
const histology = c(["9835-9836", "9811-9812,9837"]);
const category = c(["Leukemia", "Leukemia"]);
const df = frame(site, histology, category);
console.log(df);
```

Result:

```json
[
"C000,9835,Leukemia",
"C000,9836,Leukemia",
"C001,9835,Leukemia",
"C001,9836,Leukemia",
"C002,9835,Leukemia",
"C002,9836,Leukemia",
"C420,9811,Leukemia",
"C420,9812,Leukemia",
"C420,9837,Leukemia",
"C421,9811,Leukemia",
"C421,9812,Leukemia",
"C421,9837,Leukemia",
"C424,9811,Leukemia",
"C424,9812,Leukemia",
"C424,9837,Leukemia"
]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dnu2g0vr/

Comment: Thank you. I can learn from how your algorithm is set up.